# Creating txt file cannot access file being used by another process

Tags: c#, service

I'm trying to make a service that creates a text file, as a tutorial project.

However when I debug it, I get `The process cannot access the file C:\myfilepath.OnStart.txt because it is being used by another process.`

I'm expecting it to keep creating the file in a format like `OnStart(n).txt`

```
public void OnDebug()
{
    OnStart(null);
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    Timer t = new Timer(WriteTxt, null, 0, 5000);
}

public static void WriteTxt(Object i)
{
    System.IO.File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt");
}
```

Comment: You need to call .Dispose() to let go of the file `File.Create(...).Dispose();`

Comment: That definitely solves the problem of the lock up. Is there any way to have it keep creating files, just numbering them?

Comment: Yes, but I'll put it in an answer. Too long for a comment.

Comment: And in particular, if that's what you want then it should be part of the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the file you're mistakenly leaving it open which is why you can't access it next time and receive an error. You must call `.Dispose()` after you've created it to let go of the reference to the file like this:

```
File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "OnStart.txt").Dispose();
```

If you want to keep creating files then they'll need a different name each time. You could keep a global variable to keep track of this or possibly pass a value into the Write method.

**Global variable method**

```
// Keeps track of the last file number with this global variable
private int fileCount;

public void OnDebug()
{
    OnStart(null);
}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    fileCount = 0; // Or whatever you want to start with
    Timer t = new Timer(WriteTxt, null, 0, 5000);
}

public static void WriteTxt(Object i)
{
    // Creates the file name eg: OnStart1.txt
    var fileName = string.Format("OnStart{0}.txt", fileCount);

    // Use Path.Combine to make paths
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName);

    // Create the file
    File.Create(filePath).Dispose();

    // Adds 1 to the value
    fileCount++;
}
```

Results:

> OnStart0.txt
>   OnStart1.txt
>   OnStart2.txt
>   ...
>   ...
>   OnStart4999.txt